# How To make dashed lines using google charts with json object

Tags: json, google-visualization

Below is the code my json object. I want to make certain lines dashed. Could anyone tell me how to use the certainty role? I tried adding role:'certainty' inside the "p" property under "cols" and then defining "p":false/true in the rows but that didnt work. I think I am not able to get the right syntax to be used here.

```
     $scope.chartObject1 = {
                "type": "LineChart",
                "displayed": false,
                "data": {
                  "cols": [
                    {
                      "id": "month",
                      "label": "Month",
                      "type": "string",
                      "p": {}
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "Net",
                      "label": "Net",
                      "type": "number",
                      "p": {}
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "Eg",
                      "label": "EG",
                      "type": "number",
                      "p": {}
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "Sg",
                      "label": "SG",
                      "type": "number",
                      "p": {}
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "CL",
                      "label": "CL",
                      "type": "number",
                      "p": {}
                    }
                  ],
                  "rows": [
                   {
                      "c": [
                        {
                          "v": $scope.MonthGraph[7]
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.netRev[7],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.netRev[7])
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.egRev[7],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.egRev[7])
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.sgRev[7],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.sgRev[7])
                        },
                         {
                          "v": $scope.clRev[7],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.clRev[7])
                        }

                      ]
                    },
                   {
                      "c": [
                        {
                          "v": $scope.MonthGraph[8]
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.netRev[8],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.netRev[8])
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.egRev[8],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.egRev[8])
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.sgRev[8],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.sgRev[8])
                        },
                         {
                          "v": $scope.clRev[8],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.clRev[8])
                        }

                      ]
                    },
                   {
                      "c": [
                        {
                          "v": $scope.MonthGraph[9]
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.netRev[9],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.netRev[9])
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.egRev[9],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.egRev[9])
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.sgRev[9],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.sgRev[9])
                        },
                         {
                          "v": $scope.clRev[9],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.clRev[9])
                        }

                      ]
                    },
                   {
                      "c": [
                        {
                          "v": $scope.MonthGraph[10]
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.netRev[10],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.netRev[10])
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.egRev[10],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.egRev[10])
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.sgRev[10],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.sgRev[10])
                        },
                         {
                          "v": $scope.clRev[10],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.clRev[10])
                        }

                      ]
                    },
                   {
                      "c": [
                        {
                          "v": $scope.MonthGraph[11]
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.netRev[11],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.netRev[11])
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.egRev[11],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.egRev[11])
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.sgRev[11],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.sgRev[11])
                        },
                         {
                          "v": $scope.clRev[11],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.clRev[11])
                        }

                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "c": [
                        {
                          "v": $scope.MonthGraph[12]
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.netRev[12],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.netRev[12])
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.egRev[12],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.egRev[12])
                        },
                        {
                          "v": $scope.sgRev[12],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.sgRev[12])
                        },
                         {
                          "v": $scope.clRev[12],
                          "f": $scope.formatshort($scope.clRev[12])
                        }

                      ]
                    }

                  ]
```

I want to make the line from NetRev[11] to NetRev[12] dahsed. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the certainty role should be in its own column,
and follow the series column that should be dashed

in this example, the line for column `"Net"` is dashed (*NetRev[11] to NetRev[12]*)

the value of the column should be...

`true` = solid
`false` = dashed

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      "cols": [
        {
          "id": "month",
          "label": "Month",
          "type": "string",
          "p": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "Net",
          "label": "Net",
          "type": "number",
          "p": {}
        },
        {
          "role": "certainty",
          "type": "boolean",
          "p": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "Eg",
          "label": "EG",
          "type": "number",
          "p": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "Sg",
          "label": "SG",
          "type": "number",
          "p": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "CL",
          "label": "CL",
          "type": "number",
          "p": {}
        }
      ],
      "rows": [
       {
          "c": [
            {
              "v": 'JAN'
            },
            {
              "v": 10000,
              "f": "10K"
            },
            {
              "v": true
            },
            {
              "v": 11000,
              "f": "11K"
            },
            {
              "v": 12000,
              "f": "12K"
            },
            {
              "v": 13000,
              "f": "13K"
            }
          ]
        },
       {
          "c": [
            {
              "v": 'FEB'
            },
            {
              "v": 10000,
              "f": "10K"
            },
            {
              "v": true
            },
            {
              "v": 11000,
              "f": "11K"
            },
            {
              "v": 12000,
              "f": "12K"
            },
            {
              "v": 13000,
              "f": "13K"
            }
          ]
        },
       {
          "c": [
            {
              "v": 'MAR'
            },
            {
              "v": 10000,
              "f": "10K"
            },
            {
              "v": true
            },
            {
              "v": 11000,
              "f": "11K"
            },
            {
              "v": 12000,
              "f": "12K"
            },
            {
              "v": 13000,
              "f": "13K"
            }
          ]
        },
       {
          "c": [
            {
              "v": 'APR'
            },
            {
              "v": 10000,
              "f": "10K"
            },
            {
              "v": true
            },
            {
              "v": 11000,
              "f": "11K"
            },
            {
              "v": 12000,
              "f": "12K"
            },
            {
              "v": 13000,
              "f": "13K"
            }
          ]
        },
       {
          "c": [
            {
              "v": 'MAY'
            },
            {
              "v": 10000,
              "f": "10K"
            },
            {
              "v": true
            },
            {
              "v": 11000,
              "f": "11K"
            },
            {
              "v": 12000,
              "f": "12K"
            },
            {
              "v": 13000,
              "f": "13K"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "c": [
            {
              "v": 'JUN'
            },
            {
              "v": 10000,
              "f": "10K"
            },
            {
              "v": false
            },
            {
              "v": 11000,
              "f": "11K"
            },
            {
              "v": 12000,
              "f": "12K"
            },
            {
              "v": 13000,
              "f": "13K"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    });

    var container = document.getElementById('chart');
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
    chart.draw(data);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. This works. I dont have the reputation for my upvote to be shown but thanks very much.